# How to display horizontal scrollbar without go down to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

```
.well {
overflow: auto;
}
```

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar?

Comment: you can use overflow:scroll;

Comment: Can you show us any kind of code? You probably have overflow-x on the .well element and overflow-y on the body. But you should create well with height:100% and then it should work

Answer (score 5):

If you have your data inside a block element in div and you want user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar, then give it hyperlink " href="divid". when user will land on that page from any link http://exampl/#divid it will land to that div automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your data inside a block element in HTML, you can give it a fixed height using the css height property. And then use overflow-x property to add horizontal scroll bar.

```
.well {
   height: 200px;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
div { white-space: pre; }

section {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
<h1>Some content</h1>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
</section>

  
<section>
<h1>Some content</h1>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
<div>
Hi guys I have a webpage contains 100s of data listed vertically and horizontally. I have a css code for scroll bar as follows:

.well {
  overflow: auto;
}

User always need to scroll down to find the horizotal scroll bar. Is there anyway to prevent it, so that user dont need to go all the way down to find his scroll bar? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow-x: scroll or overflow: scroll

https://jsfiddle.net/h4bjLL0g/

```
body {
   overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.well {
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate space left on the screen and than adjust element height to fit it. Below is a code, it may require some fiddling, but it's working in basic situations. Also remember to call it on resize event, to adjust to such situations:

```
const element = document.getElementById('specialElement');
const elementSize = element.getBoundingClientRect();
const elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
const windowHeightValue = window.innerHeight;
const elementHeight = windowHeightValue - elementSize.top - 2 * parseInt(elementStyle.marginTop, 0);
element.style.height = elementHeight + 'px';
```

Element parent has to have horizontal scrolling enabled. And element should be the element that goes off the charts.